# Sequelize one to many assocation in multiple files

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, bluebird

I am working on one to many assocations with sequelize. Most tutorials and documentation shows examples when both models are defined in the same file.
I currently have two files, first city.js:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
var Country = require('./country');

var City = sequelize.define("City", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'id',
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },...
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false
});

City.belongsTo(Country, {foreignKey : 'countryId', as: 'Country'});

Promise.promisifyAll(City);
module.exports = City;
```

And a second file country.js:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
var City = require('./city');

var Country = sequelize.define("Country", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'id',
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  ...
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
  paranoid: false
});

Country.hasMany(City, {foreignKey : 'countryId', as: 'Cities'});

Promise.promisifyAll(Country);
module.exports = Country;
```

When I import both modules and try to instantiate object:

```
var City = require('../model/external/city');
var CountryRepository = require('../repository/external/countryRepository');

CountryRepository.findById(1).then(function(country) {
    var city = City.build();
    city.name = 'Paris';
    city.setCountry(country);
    console.log('OK');
});
```

I get the following error:

> throw new Error(this.name + '.' +
>   Utils.lowercaseFirst(Type.toString()) + ' called with something
>   that\'s not an instance of Sequelize.Model')

Is the problem that models are promisified before they are exported from model or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem with your code, would need to run it to be sure.

But as you were looking for an example, take a look at this example from [Sequelize Github](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/tree/master/express-main-example/sequelize/models).

It declares models in different files and associate them in the `index.js`.

Later you can reference your other model with a simple `model` atribute **`model.Country`**:

```
City.belongsTo(model.Country, {foreignKey : 'countryId', as: 'Country'});
```

For instance, [user.js](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/user.js).

Comment: Thank you, with a little index.js modification I got the results I wanted

Comment: Can u elaborate in detail, when I have to put the code as I did exactly same as user.js but can't getting an error like { SequelizeEagerLoadingError: ticket is not associated to ticketComment!

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by following this advice (i.e. defining all the associations in one file). But is this really a good idea? To see a model's information, you have to see the model declaration AND the association file. I wonder if both model declarations and associations can be stored in one file

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the associations after having export all your models

I had the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I created a technique that I think is really nice and even allows for composite unique keys across even a foreign key.

I'll give an example with a basic **user.js** model class file

**models/user.js**

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize){
    class User extends Model {}
    return User.init({
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
      },
      trading_system_key: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
      },
    }, {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
      indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['trading_system_key'] }]
    });
};
```

This shows a simple example of the user class, no associations yet, but the next file will use it.

**models/algorithm.js**

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(sequelize){
    class Algorithm extends Model {}
    UserModel = User(sequelize);//@JA - Gets a defined version of user class

    var AlgorithmFrame = Algorithm.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        user_Id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: { 
                model: UserModel,
                key: 'id',
            },
        }
    }, {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Algorithm',
      indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['name','user_id'] }]
    });

    return AlgorithmFrame
};
```

This example shows how you can create a foreign key reference without having to say belongsTo or HasOne etc... This comes in handy when you need to create composite keys.

For example, note that I put `indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['name','user_id'] }]`

This makes it so the name and user_id can't be the same together (a composite key).  So for example if the name was Joe and the user_id was 1 and I tried to create another record with the same details it would reject it, but if I created something with the name Rachel and user_id 1 it would allow it, since it's only unique if both are the same.

Doing a composite key is not possible to my knowledge unless you set it up this way.

The other advantage of this technique is the models are in a separate file and defined as classes!

**So how do I use these?**

(In your file you define the sequelize connection...)
**api.js**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const User = require('../models/user');
const Algorithm = require('../models/algorithm');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'passwordhere', {
      host: 'db',
      dialect: 'mysql' /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */
    });

const UserModel = User(sequelize);
const AlogorithmModel = Algorithm(sequelize);

(async () => {
      try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        await UserModel.sync({ alter: true });
        await AlogorithmModel.sync({ alter: true });

        //Do something with the models now....
        //Etc...

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
      }

});
```

This technique works because of how the class files are defined.  In typical software development you include the class and have reference to it and instantiate it, but in this case **we are passing in the instantiated version of it already**

For example, you will note in the class file I define the `class user extends model {}` and it's simply empty inside.  Then we return an instantiated version of the class.  When you use module.exports in this way it is actually expecting a parameter of the sequelize connection instance.

This is why in the api.js file I say `const User = require('../models/user');`, this gets reference to the 'function' that the file is returning.

The function doesn't do anything unless you pass it sequelize, so the next line you see...

```
const UserModel = User(sequelize);
```

By doing this you are able to have your models in separate files and have them be classes and they can still have associations and even composite indexes!

Hope this helps you out.

UPDATE::

If you want the onUpdate or onDelete cascade option simply define it with the model like this.

```
 algorithm_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            references: { 
                model: AlgorithmModel,
                key: 'id',
            }
        },
```

You can also set if you want it to be null or not, HOWEVER, keep in mind that allowNull will NOT work with the 'alter' table command unless the foreign key has been DROPPED first! the onUpdate and onDelete appear to work with alter just fine though.

Comment: The one thing I don't have accounted in this is the onUpdate and onDelete cascade option settings, I'm not sure where to put these yet.  So if someone can amend my answer with that I would appreciate it!

Comment: Ok good news I figured out how to do onUpdate and on Delete cascade options! Will update my answer