# Define models' relations in models' files - sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I saw a few questions with similar question/problem, but they are based on older versions of sequelize.js and unfortunately these answers cannot be applied to v.4.

I define two models: `User` and `Tag`. User can have multiple tags, tags can belong to one user (1:m relation). I have two separate files which define my models:

`User.js` file:

```
import Tag from './Tag';

const userFields = { /* my fields definitions... */ };

const User = sequelize.define('user', userFields);

User.hasMany(Tag, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  constraints: true,
});

export default User;
```

`Tag.js` file:

```
import User from './User';

const tagFields = { /* tag fields definitions... */ };

const Tag = sequelize.define('tag', tagFields);

Tag.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  constraints: false
});

export default Tag;
```

Obviously it doesn't work beacause these two files try to import each other and one of them see's other as `undefined` and I see error that `User called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`.

Docs only give examples similar to the one below, where models are defined in one file:

```
const Player = this.sequelize.define('player', {/* attributes */});
const Team  = this.sequelize.define('team', {/* attributes */});

Player.belongsTo(Team); // Will add a teamId attribute to Player to hold the primary key value for Team
```

So, my question is: how can I define associations between models in models' files? I know that one solution is to create a function (the one which will create associations) in a separate file and call it after models are defined. But I want to keep these associations with models' definitions. How can I do that in sequelize@v.4?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the library version does not matter. What actually matters is where you put the code responsible for declaring the associations. I know it is not very pretty, but what you have to do is to declare your associations outside both of the two files declaring the schemas.

This answers explains it and shows the example used by the library https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877672/614277

Comment: I already saw similar answer to the one you linked, but I am wondering if this is the only way to do this? Do I really have to create a separate file with all relations between my models?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way, like you said, they will see each other as undefined. it is ugly, but that'll have to do